# How to parse Json object in ajax

Tags: java, jquery

I am not able to parse tje Json object returned from the servlet in ajax,

I need to put json object values in there relative field

From my java code i am sending the below String in the form of JSON

```
String  webVisitorDetails = "{"+"companyName : \""+webVisitor.getCompanyName()+ "\","+
                                                "address : \""+webVisitor.getProfessionalAddress()+ "\","+
                                                "city : \""+webVisitor.getCity()+ "\","+
                                                "zipCode : \""+webVisitor.getZipCode()+ "\","+
                                                "clientId : \""+webVisitor.getCustomerAccountNumber()+ "\"}";
```

In ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ships",
    data: {
        email: email.toString()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            console.log(k + " Value " + v);
            $("#city").text(v.city);
            $("#zipcode").text(v.getZipCode);
            $("#Adress").text(v.getProfessionalAddress);
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("error:", data);
    },
    type: "post",
    datatype:"json",
});
```

Comment: Create JSON using `org.json` library. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Comment: Your string does not appear to be JSON (although it is hard to tell since you are showing us the Java that generates it and not the JSON text itself). As iNan says - don't build JSON by mashing together strings, use a proper serializer.

Comment: Good point. There is also [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome), which can be used (inter alia) to map Java objects to JSON and vice versa. Might be too powerful for your use case but I do not know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the jQuery setting is [`dataType`](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax) with a capital T. To do the JSON parsing manually, use the [`parseJSON`](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.parseJSON) function. However, if you set the `Content-Type` of your servlet response to `application/json`, the datatype should be auto-detected.

After you fixed this: Does it work? What is the value of the `data` argument of your `success` handler?

```
console.debug(data);
```

As Neal already said, JSON parsing expects valid JSON strings starting with jQuery 1.4. You can validate your JSON [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

> [In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

To avoid the manual building of JSON strings, use something like the [JSON-java](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) processor (from [iNan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470482/how-to-parse-json-object-in-ajax#comment15144336_11470482)) or other Java implementations listed on [json.org](http://json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You json string is **incorrect**

The keys **must** be surrounded by double quotes.

[Read the requirements here](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: Can you please help me how to write json string.

Comment: @KunalVashist See the website.

Comment: @KunalVashist [Here is some documentation on JSON for Java](http://www.json.org/java/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's creating a problem because of the single-inverted comma ('), then just do:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data.replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

If that is the case then it should work for you...

Comment: Don't see where `'` is used in the question. Generally, this kind of problem should be fixed server-side, so valid JSON is produced and served to the clients.